# db_update after a submit button is clicked

Tags: 7, database

I want to update a field. This the code I am using to write values in the database.

```php
$enrollment = array(
  'database' => 'enrollment',
  'username' => 'postgres', 
  'password' => '', 
  'host' => 'localhost', 
  'driver' => 'pgsql',
);
  
Database::addConnectionInfo('myid', 'default', $enrollment);

db_set_active('enrollment');

db_update('student')
  ->fields(array('picture' => 'Yucks'))
  ->condition('studid', '101-03043', '=')
  ->execute();

db_set_active();
```

The code doesn't work. Instead of saving values in the database, it throws an error.

> [image: screenshot]

What do I need to change in the code to make it work?

Comment: Have you made entry in settings.php for "enrollment" database.

Comment: Confirm if you have `student` table in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `db_update()` would work with `db_set_active()`, `db_set_active()` is completely unnecessary in Drupal 7.

Instead, you can just use the following code.

```php
Database::getConnection('default', 'enrollment')
  ->update($table, $options);
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it doesn't require to change the active connection, which is used from every Drupal core and contributed modules.